# Conditional execution after a delete trigger in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I need to prepare a SQLite trigger for following condition -

1. There are three tables - retail_store, wholesale_store and product
2. Tables retail_store and wholesale_store have column product_id from table product

Now I want to write a delete trigger such that if a product is deleted from retail_store and if it is not in table wholesale_store, then that product record should be deleted from product table.

** I understand as a practice it may not be a good idea to delete a product record like this. Please take this question only as a technical complication.

Thanks for considering this one. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the following sql statemen is useful for you, but i can't assure the syntax is correct.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER after_retail_store_delete after delete ON retail_store
    WHEN ((select count() from  wholesale_store where productid = OLD.id) = 0)
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM product WHERE productid = OLD.id ;
    END ;
```

Comment: AWESOME wenhm!!! It works perfect. I just modified the delete query as the table name should be product. I can't believe why your reputation appears as just '1' while answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't actually need a trigger. I would consider making use of cascading delete. Are you using foreign keys? Check this out:

> The ON DELETE and ON UPDATE action associated with each foreign key in
>   an SQLite database is one of "NO ACTION", "RESTRICT", "SET NULL", "SET
>   DEFAULT" or "CASCADE". If an action is not explicitly specified, it
>   defaults to "NO ACTION".
>
> NO ACTION: Configuring "NO ACTION" means just that: when a parent key
>   is modified or deleted from the database, no special action is taken.
>
> RESTRICT: The "RESTRICT" action means that the application is
>   prohibited from deleting (for ON DELETE RESTRICT) or modifying (for ON
>   UPDATE RESTRICT) a parent key when there exists one or more child keys
>   mapped to it. The difference between the effect of a RESTRICT action
>   and normal foreign key constraint enforcement is that the RESTRICT
>   action processing happens as soon as the field is updated - not at the
>   end of the current statement as it would with an immediate constraint,
>   or at the end of the current transaction as it would with a deferred
>   constraint. Even if the foreign key constraint it is attached to is
>   deferred, configuring a RESTRICT action causes SQLite to return an
>   error immediately if a parent key with dependent child keys is deleted
>   or modified.
>
> SET NULL: If the configured action is "SET NULL", then when a parent
>   key is deleted (for ON DELETE SET NULL) or modified (for ON UPDATE SET
>   NULL), the child key columns of all rows in the child table that
>   mapped to the parent key are set to contain SQL NULL values.
>
> SET DEFAULT: The "SET DEFAULT" actions are similar to "SET NULL",
>   except that each of the child key columns is set to contain the
>   columns default value instead of NULL. Refer to the CREATE TABLE
>   documentation for details on how default values are assigned to table
>   columns.
>
> CASCADE: A "CASCADE" action propagates the delete or update operation
>   on the parent key to each dependent child key. For an "ON DELETE
>   CASCADE" action, this means that each row in the child table that was
>   associated with the deleted parent row is also deleted. For an "ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE" action, it means that the values stored in each
>   dependent child key are modified to match the new parent key values.

Read more here:
http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

Comment: Thanks Jason. There is an issue though. As I specified the product should only be deleted from table product ONLY IF the product record don't exist in table wholesale_store. Its also important to understand that this operation is like if you delete a child record, then delete parent record too, if the child record don't exist in any other table.

Answer (score -1):

Hi reading documentation [Sqllite Foreing Key](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) use that SQL command:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```